# HighStock/HighCharts add point from JSON dynamically to series (events)

Tags: json, highcharts

I have a Highstock graph to show temperature data from multiple JSON sources. The page is build using the compare multiple series demo file.

I now try to dynamically add data to the series using an event but it seems it never gets called or isn't doing what I expect/hope is is doing :(

My code looks like this:

```js
var seriesOptions = [],
   seriesCounter = 0,
   names = ['Temperature',  'Humidity'];


   var chart; // global        
   function requestData() {
    
    

    $.getJSON('JSON/new_Temperature.json', 
     function(point){

     var series = this.series[0];

     // add the point

     series.addPoint(point);

     // call it again after one second

     setInterval(requestData, 3000); 

    }); 
   }

   /**
   * Create the chart when all data is loaded
   * @returns {undefined}
   */
   function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
     events: {
               load: requestData
     },
     rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1,
      buttons: [{
       type: 'hour',
       count: 1,
       text: '1h'
      }, {
       type: 'minute',
       count: 5,
       text: '5minutes'
      }]
     },
     series: seriesOptions
    });
   }

   function success(data) {
    var name = this.url.match(/(Temperature|Humidity)/)[0];
    var i = names.indexOf(name);

    seriesOptions[i] = {
       name: name,
       data: data,
       type: 'spline'
       }; 

    seriesCounter += 1;

    if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
     createChart();
    }
   }

   Highcharts.getJSON(
    'JSON/Temperature.json',
    success
   );
   Highcharts.getJSON(
    'JSON/Humidity.json',
    success
   );
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/themes/gray.js"></script>

  <div id="container" style="height: 800px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

When I added the above snippet it gave me an error on line 14 which is the `var series = this.series[0];` so I guess I'm doing something wrong there? But I don't know what...

The used JSON files contain the data like this:

```
[[1578508367000,33.8],[1578508491000,33.8],[1578508506000,33.8],[1578508523000,33.8],[1578508539000,33.8],[1578508554000,33.8],[1578508570000,33.8],[1578508586000,33.8],[1578508602000,33.8],[1578508619000,33.8],[1578508635000,33.8],[1578508652000,33.8],[1578508668000,33.9],[1578508683000,33.8],[1578508699000,33.8],[1578508715000,33.8],[1578508731000,33.8],[1578508746000,33.8],[1578508762000,33.8],[1578508778000,33.8],[1578508795000,33.8],[1578508811000,33.8],[1578508827000,33.8],[1578508843000,33.8],[1578508860000,33.8],[1578508876000,33.8],[1578508892000,33.8],[1578508908000,33.8],[1578508923000,33.8],[1578508939000,33.8],[1578508955000,33.8]]
```

and the JSON I use to insert a point only contains the newest value: `[[1578508367000,33.8]]`

I guess I need to call the **getJSON** inside **requestData()** multiple times!? One for each series.

Currently I use **setInterval** but is there a way to do it whenever the JSON is refreshed/overwritten?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

**EDIT**: In response to Sebastian Wędzel as my intentions might not have been entirely clear :)

What I was trying to do is the following. I have 4 json files, 2 of them contain temperature/humidity values for the past days and 2 of them only contain the latest measurements. I have a PHP script updating all 4 periodically.
When my page loads it loads the 2 big json files as separate series into the chart. After the chart is loaded I want it to periodically add the new measurements to the graph without the need of reloading the entire page.
It is actually similar to this example: [Live data from dynamic CSV](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/live-data) but I'm using JSON (although CSV would be a possibility) and I need multiple series. Both of which I didn't get to work with that CSV example.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have got Highcharts error #16 because in your html you have added the Highcharts and Highstock scripts.

https://www.highcharts.com/errors/16/

2. Notice that **this** inside the requestData function points to the **getJSON** functionality, not to the chart object - that means this.series is undefined.

I assumed that getJSON for temperature and humidity works fine and the chart was initialized and now I am not sure if you want to add the whole data to the existing data or add points one by one from fetched data.

- Here is an approach to add the points one by one:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s0o1gL3z/

```
function requestData() {

  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhene',
    function(data) {

      var series = chart.series[0],
        i = 0;

      // add the point
      function addPointToSeries() {
        series.addPoint(data[i]);
        i++;
        if (i === data.length) {
          clearInterval(addPoints)
        }
      }

      var addPoints = setInterval(addPointToSeries, 1000);
    });
}
```

- here how to add whole data to the existing one:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zdpxwe1k/

```
    function requestData() {

      $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhene',
        function(data) {
          var series = chart.series[0];

                data.forEach(d => {
        series.addPoint(d, false);
    })
          chart.redraw();

        });
    }
```

---

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Thanks!!! I made an edit to the original post as I think my intentions weren't completely clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working.

```js
  var chart;

  function requestData() {

   $.getJSON('Humidity.json',
    function(data) {
    chart.addSeries({name: "Humidity", data: data});
    }
   );
   $.getJSON('Temperature.json',
    function(data) {
    chart.addSeries({name: "Temperature", data: data});
    }
   );

   setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON('new_Humidity.json',
        function(data0) {
      console.log("Humidity data = " + data0[data0.length - 1]);
                     chart.series[0].addPoint(data0[data0.length - 1], true, true);
        }
    );

    $.getJSON('new_Temperature.json',
        function(data1) {
      console.log("Temperature data = " + data1[data1.length - 1]);
                     chart.series[1].addPoint(data1[data1.length - 1], true, true);
        }
    );
   }, 1000);
  }


  chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  chart: {
   events: {
   load() {
    requestData();
   }
   }
  },
  series: []
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
  

  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/themes/gray.js"></script>

  <div id="container" style="height: 800px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

I can probably change data0 and data1 back to just data.... And the data0[data0.length - 1] to data0[0] but I might want to check to see if it also works when I read the entire json and use the last value but I suspect it will be slow :(

Comment: for the record.... It works but I forgot to compensate for the asynchronability of getJSON... So I match the name to get the correct series index..